# Find the original amount of petrol in the tanker

Tags: geometry

A oil tanker transfers petrol in an underground petrol storage tank measuring 80 m by 30 m by 40 cm. The storage tank already has 15 liters petrol in it.

When the petrol is filled up to height 5/8 of the storage tank, 4/9 of the tanker was still filled with petrol.What was the amount of petrol in the tanker in the beginning?

**Below is my attempt**

```
Let the initial amount of petrol in the tanker be x liters

Given information

a) storage tank already has 15 liters = 15000 cu.cm of petrol

b) petrol is filled up to height 5/8 of the storage tank = 40* 5/8 = 25cm

Now, we have the equation as 

15000 + (80*30*25) = 80*30*4x/9 

or, 15000 + 60000 = 9600x/9

x =  70.3125 cu.cm  = 0.0703125 liters



But this is wrong. The correct answer is 81 liters.

Please help to understand where I'm wrong?

Thanks for the support
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add $15000$ with $(80 \times 30 \times25)$.

The amount of fuel added to the storage $=(80 \times 30 \times25)-15000=45$ liter

Now $\frac{5}{9}$ of the tanker is $45$ liter, then the volume of the tanker should be $81$ liter